# Compare data between postgres tand snowflake table with same DDL

Tags: database, postgresql, bigdata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl

I have migrated few tables, each with at least 200M rows, from postgresDB to snowflake and now i need to compare data between both to make sure data migration activity completed successfully. Is there any way i can compare tables effectively and fast. Schema/table structure in both DB's is same. I was thinking to create either view or materialised view to store MD5 and compare. Would that be correct approach?